# How to convert string to as_bytes in typescript?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, anchor-test, typescript, anchor-lang

So, I have a PDA seed where I'm hashing a `string` (which is converted to bytes) and converting the hash result `to_string` and then `as_bytes`.

code:

`anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(name.as_bytes()).to_string().as_bytes()`

how to produce this in typescript?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to translate that Rust code to TypeScript, then it'd be something along these lines (I haven't tested this):

```
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';

Buffer.from(sha256(name))
```

If you don't want to use `crypto-js`, Node now has a [Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module but it's a bit more involved.

Comment: `Max seed length exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

```
let utf8Encode = new TextEncoder();
utf8Encode.encode("abc")
// Uint8Array [ 97, 98, 99 ]
```

Here is the original answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray

Comment: doesn't work in ts. TextEncoder not found.

Comment: For this specific thing, I think `anchor.utils.bytes.utf8` provides encoder/decoder already?